# How to write decimal values in words

Tags: numbers

I have 1210.802 units in a mutual fund. How do I write it in words?

"One thousand two hundred and ten..." How do I write the decimal units here?

Comment: "One thousand two hundred and ten" ... that "and" is British-speak, often omitted in the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder: if you must complete the form using words, is it necessary to include the fractional part?  One could say:

- *I own approximately twelve hundred and ten shares*.

or,

- *I have just over one thousand, two hundred and ten units*.

If you must be absolutely precise, though, you might use:

- *One thousand, two hundred and ten units, plus eight hundred and two thousandths of a unit*.

My goodness, though!  After you write such a monstrosity, do what Barrie suggested, and put the number in parentheses.

Comment: Hmm, whether it's "necessary" to include the fractional part surely depends on the context. If each share is worth $10,000, I don't think I'd want to just forget about the fractional share. Well, maybe if I had ten million dollars another eight thousand would seem like pocket change. Sadly, I'm unlikely to ever know.

Answer (score 5):

And the numbers afterwards are individual:

One thousand two hundred and ten point eight oh two.

But, as per @Barrie, why? I can think of no case where this would be necessary or appropriate.

Comment: And it risks confusion to do so.

Comment: I need to fill up a form wherein I have to mention the number of units in numbers and words.

Comment: The conventional rule in writing is that once a number passes two digits, we write it as Hindu-Arabic digits and not in words. But if a form requires you to write it in words, then I guess that's what you have to do. They probably want you to write it both ways as a double-check against errors: If the two agree, that's a good sign, if not, then one or the other or both are mistakes and they'll have to check back with you to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing the values on a check, say for $193.34, when writing it in words it is customarily done as:

> One hundred ninety three and 34/100

Perhaps for your numbers you would use the same convention.  For 1210.802, you would write:

> One thousand two hundred ten and 802/1000

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you wouldn’t. In speech, you say the decimal point as ‘point’.

Comment: I need to fill up a form wherein I have to mention the number of units in numbers and words.

Comment: @The King: You could write ‘one thousand, two hundred and ten and eight hundred and two thousandths units’, perhaps followed by the number in brackets, but it looks very odd.

Comment: In the US, seeing those three "and"s in there might look strange.  But he did say "fill up a form" so I assume he is not from the US.